# AWS X-Ray Tracing from Lambda to SNS to SQS to another Lambda (Python3, boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-xray

I have a question similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862529/using-the-same-x-ray-tracing-id-for-multiple-lambda-functions/69863262#69863262). I want to generate a service map that allows me to view the orchestration of my serverless architecture, especially across SNS and SQS between 2 lambdas. The difference being that I am using Amazon's SQS in place of RabbitMQ.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272207/aws-x-ray-how-to-propagate-traceid-through-lambda-sns-lambda), and the [linked forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=874978#xD59E2) in the answer suggests that this feature is already available.

From what I have read in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python-awssdkclients.html), it suggests that I only need to `patch` the `boto` library. Going by the examples, I included the following in my relevant python files:

```
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all

patch_all()
```

However, when testing my lambda, the service map still appears as 2 individual traces, with the trace ending at my SNS.
[image: Broken AWS X-Ray Map]

Does anyone know what may be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS SNS currently lacks the capability to pass X-Ray trace context to SQS subscribers. It only supports HTTP/HTTPS and Lambda subscribers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-sns.html

As a result the trace is not propagated from SNS to SQS and therefore you see 2 disconnected traces.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested yet but I found this post (2023-02-09) claiming the propagation is now supported:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/02/amazon-sns-x-ray-active-tracing-visualize-analyze-debug-application-performance/